# Inserting VB.net Label to mysql table

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How to Inserting Label.text data into mySql table.
i have no problem with textbox.text but i can't figure out how it with Label.text
i try the same code with textbox.text

```
parameterB_Answer.Value = TextBox1.Text
```

it work find but when i try with

```
parameterB_Answer.Value = Label1.Text
```

mySqlReader seems can't read it.

Update:

1.1.1 is label1.text. My Idea is to insert the text "1.1.1" from Label1 as Primary key and the Textbox(textbox1.text) as the following

my code is:

```
Try
    Dim StrSQL As String = "INSERT INTO boranga" & _
                           "(IdBorangA,Answers)" & _
                           "VALUES (@B_IdA,@B_Answer);"
    Dim myCommand As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(StrSQL, conn.open)
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim parameterB_IdA As MySqlParameter = New MySqlParameter("@B_IdA", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 300)
    parameterB_IdA.Value = Label1.Text
    Dim parameterB_Answer As MySqlParameter = New MySqlParameter("@B_Answer", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 300)
    parameterB_Answer.Value = TextBox1.Text
    With myCommand.Parameters
        .Add(parameterB_IdA)
        .Add(parameterB_Answer)
    End With

    Dim result As MySqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    MsgBox("Tersimpan", vbYes, "boranga")

Catch SqlEx As MySqlException
    Throw New Exception(SqlEx.Message.ToString())
End Try
```

but when I change the value of Label1.text (1.1.1) to 111, it works just fine. probably because I put INT for the column for label1.text to fill while "1.1.1" isn't integer

thank a lot

PS:seems i can't post image because low of reputation

Comment: This should not be possible, a text is a text. Are you sure your Label1 has a text? Please show your code.

Comment: if mySQLReader cant read it then what it the error message? in both situations you are assigning a string to `parameterB_Answer.Value`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code format first of all:

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
Dim conn As MySqlConnection

'Connect to the database using these credentials
conn = New MySqlConnection
conn.ConnectionString = "server=your server site (generally long url); user id=login id for mysql user; password=self explanatory; database=name of the DB you're trying to reach"

'Try and connect (conn.open)
Try
    conn.Open()

Catch myerror As MySqlException 'If it fails do this... (i.e. no internet connection, etc.)
    MsgBox("Error connecting to database. Check your internet connection.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
End Try


'MySQL query (where to call for information)
Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter

'Tell where to find the file with the emails/passes stored
Dim sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM the database you selected above WHERE Email = '" & txtEmail.Text & "' AND Password = '" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
myCommand.Connection = conn
myCommand.CommandText = sqlquery

'Start query
myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
Dim myData As MySqlDataReader
myData = myCommand.ExecuteReader

If myData.HasRows = 0 Then
    MsgBox("Invalid email address or password.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

Else
    MsgBox("Logged in as " & txtEmail.Text & ".", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

    Me.Close()

End If
```

End Sub

And to insert label.text try replacing one of the textbox.text fields first and see if it will accept it.  If it does, then the answer was all in the formatting.

Also, do not forget to call:

```
imports mysql.data.mysqlclient
```

and make sure to add the mysql.data reference.